# What does the "it" stand for in the MongoDB shell?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

You see it when the results of a `find` are too long to display in the terminal.

```
Type "it" for more
```

There's a good chance "it" just stands for [it](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/it?s=t), but I'm not certain and I can't seem to find any documentation on it. For all I know, "it" could also be an abbreviation for "increment through".

What does it mean and is it convention to use "it" for pagination in the terminal?

Comment: Documentation on Queries: The mongo shell will prompt the user to “Type it” to continue iterating the next 20 results. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongo-shell/#queries

Answer (score 4):

It means "iterate", since your query has returned only a subset of the results.

Answer (score 0):

'it' is the command for "display the following collection, while there still is a collection."

Its equivalent in JavaScript is:

```
cur = db.collection_name_here.find()

if (cur.hasNext()){
     
     cur.next();
 
 }
```

Comment: This tells me what "it" does and not what "it" stands for. If @chaseadamsio had left their comment as an answer and not as a question, I wouldn't accepted it. Further, since 'displayBatchSize' directly affects the number of results displayed by "it", I'd accept an answer that linked to https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/reference/configure-shell-settings/#configurable-settings and explained why it stands for "iterate".